# Can we always find a prime by this procedure?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that we start with some prime $p$. We then take a square of $p$ and sum that square with some number from the set $\{1,2,...p\}$ to obtain some other prime. We then cube $p$ and sum that cube with some number  from the set $\{1,2,...p^2\}$ to obtain some prime again. At $n$-th step we take $p$ to the power of $n$ and sum $p^n$ with some number from the set $\{1,2,..p^{n-1}\}$ to obtain some prime. We do that until it is possible to do that.

An example: $p=7$. Squaring gives $7^2=49$ we now must sum $49$ with some number from the set $\{1,2,...7\}$ to obtain a prime. We can choose $4$ because $49+4=53$, a prime. We then cube $7$ to obtain $7^3=343$ and now we choose some number from the set $\{1,2,...49\}$ and we can choose $4$ to obtain $343+4=347$. And so on...

> Is there a prime $p$ such that this procedure fails after a finite number of steps?

A question, phrased differently is:

> Is there for every prime $p$ a prime in the set $\{p^n+1,...p^n+p^{n-1}\}$ for every $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{2\}$?

Comment: Always in $[p^2,2p^2]$ there is a prime (Bertrand's Postulate, B.P.). Since $p^2\lt p^2+p\lt 2p^2$ your conjecture is a weakening of B.P. restraint to odd primes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the highly likely truth of [Oppermann's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture), there will be a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$. The slightly shaky region is up to about $200,$ after which gaps between primes are comfortably smaller than the square root of the relevant primes.

Actual [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) become relatively  far smaller as $n$ gets big - the largest numerical prime gap among the fully identified prime set is only $1510$, at $p\approx 6.8\times 10^{18}$

As Robert Israel mentioned, this (first step) is an open issue, Oppermann's conjecture as stated. The difficulty of proving the bounds of such prime gaps is out of step with the size of gaps themselves, the largest of which are far smaller than the known bounds.

Comment: Is it known that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2 + n$? I thought that it's still an open problem if there's always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n + 1)^2$, and your claim is strictly stronger than that.

Comment: The statement that there is a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$ is part of [Opperman's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture).  It is still open.

Comment: @Joffan An open problem is not "actually true", otherwise it is not "open". We should not use such a formulation even if "everybody is convinced" of the truth. It is OK to say that almost surely the claim is true because of the Oppermann's conjecture.

Comment: @Peter I understand the difference. I completely disagree that the presence of a conjecture makes the truth of the matter more likely; rather, here, the disparity between bounds and found reality is the driver for conviction.  Also please advise what you find problematic with my answer that I'm guessing you downvoted. Comments are not part of the answer.

Comment: @Joffan "in general" is the formulation I have problems with. I suggest the formulation : "Assuming Oppermann's conjecture, there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $n^2+n$ $\cdots$". Then, I will upvote the answer.

Comment: @Peter - modified to put the conjecture higher up the answer text.

Comment: @Joffan I upvoted now.